# Serialization and Deserialization of a Map<Object, Object>

Tags: java, networking, serialization, gson, deserialization

Maybe I'm only being stupid right now, but I've been struggling really hard.

I am writing a networking application that interacts with another library right now.
The messages that this library produces are in the form `Map<Path, Object>`. These messages now need to be serialized.
I do not know of what type these `Object`'s are. They are only transferred between two objects that can handle them, but for this need to be serialized.

I however struggle to understand how to do it. I've tried with Gson already but don't unterstand how to solve it.

Code looks something like this:

```
public interface Path extends Serializable{}

public interface Network{

    public Map<Path, Object> getSendMessages();

    public void receiveMessage(Map<Path, Object> message);

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Network nw1 = NetworkProvider.getNetwork();
       Network nw2 = NetworkProvider.getNetwork();
       //I don't know what these actually do with the messages.
       while(true) {
           Map<Path, Object> message = nw1.getSendMessages();
           //__________What to do here?__________________

           SerializedMessage serializedMessage = ....
           Map<Path, Object> deserializedMessage = ....

           //____________________________________________
           nw2.receiveMessage(deserializedMessage);
       }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can easily serialize and deserialize an Object `Map` by using `ObjectMapper` from `Jackson`.

This is an example of serializing:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonResult = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
  .writeValueAsString(message);
```

For more information, check this link:

[Map Serialization](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map)